# Plotly updating trace with marker symbol resets marker size

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

**Problem:**

I am using [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/bubble-charts/) .

When i try to update `marker.symbol`, it resets `marker.size`

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/sa0rbfg8/6/

**Code:**

```
var trace1 = {
   x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   y: [10, 11, 12, 13],
   mode: 'markers',
   marker: {
     size: [40, 60, 80, 100]
   }
 };
 var data = [trace1];
 var layout = {
   title: 'Marker Size',
   showlegend: false,
   height: 400,
   width: 480
 };

 Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
 $('#changes').click(function() {
   var data_update = {
     'marker': {
       symbol: 'square'
     }
   };
   Plotly.restyle('myDiv', data_update, [0]);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that size is a property of the markers, when you update the trace with the new marker object you are overwritting with a new json that does not contain the sizes. Something like this would do the trick.

```
var trace1 = {
   x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   y: [10, 11, 12, 13],
   mode: 'markers',
   marker: {
     size: [40, 60, 80, 100]
   }
 };
 var data = [trace1];
 var layout = {
   title: 'Marker Size',
   showlegend: false,
   height: 400,
   width: 480
 };

 Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
 $('#changes').click(function() {
   var data_update = {
     'marker.symbol': 'square'
     }
   };
   Plotly.restyle('myDiv', data_update, [0]);
 });
```

Comment: But the document does not say anything about this.I can update marker.color without providing size

Comment: Digging a bit deeper into the docs I found that the correct way to modify a sub-attribute is to nest it in the string, that way plotly does not overwrite the entire object. I edited the code above with that modification.